# PHP is there a true() function?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing a function named `all` to check all elements inside an array `$arr`, returning a single `boolean` value (based of `$f` return value). This is working fine passing custom functions (see the code with `$gte0` been passed to `all`).

However sometimes one want just check that an array contains all `true` values: `all(true, $arr)` will not work becase `true` is passed as `boolean` (and `true` is not a function name). Does PHP have a native `true()` like function?

```
function all($f, array $arr)
{
    return empty($arr) ? false : array_reduce($arr, function($v1, $v2) use ($f) {
        return $f($v1) && $f($v2);
    }, true);
}

$test = array(1, 6, 2);
$gte0 = function($v) { return $v >= 0; }

var_dump(all($gte0, $test)); // True

$test = array(true, true, false);
$id   = function($v) { return $v; } // <-- this is what i would avoid
var_dump(all($id, $test)); // False

all(true, $test); // NOT WORKING because true is passed as boolean
all('true', $test); // NOT WORKING because true is not a function
```

**EDIT**: another way could be checking `$f` in `all` function:

```
$f = is_bool($f) ? ($f ? function($v) { return $v; }
    : function($v) { return !$v; } ): $f;
```

After adding this, calling `all` with `true` is perfectly fine.

Comment: this is a very misleading way to write code, IMO. Especially your second piece of code, is pretty hard to understand the right flow

Comment: @yes123 you should add IMHO at the end of your comment.

Comment: @Gremo: Comments are always declarative and never share opinion. That's why they are called comments ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intval` might do what you're looking for (especially as the array only contains integers in your example):

```
var_dump(all('intval', $test)); // False
```

However, [many types to integer conversions are undefined in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) and with float this will round towards zero, so this might not be what you want.

The more correct "function" would be the opposite of boolean true: `empty`, but it's not a function, so you can't use it (and invert the return value):

```
var_dump(!all('empty', $test)); // Does not work!
```

And there is no function called `boolval` or similar in PHP, so write it yourself if you need it ;)

Additionally your `all` function could be optimized. While iterating, if the current result is already `FALSE`, the end result will always be `FALSE`. And no need to call `$f()` `n * 2` times anyway:

```
function all($f, array $arr)
{
    $result = (bool) $arr;
    foreach($arr as $v) if (!$f($v)) return FALSE;
    return $result;
}
```

**Edit:** [knittl is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315331/367456) pointing to `array_filter`, it converts to boolean with no function given which seems cool as there is no "boolval" function:

```
function all($f, array $arr)
{   
    return ($c = count($arr))
        && ($f ? $arr = array_map($f, $arr) : 1)
        && $c === count(array_filter($arr));
}

var_dump(all(0, $test)); // False
```

Making the first function parameter optional will do you a proper bool cast on each array element thanks to `array_filter`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the most relevant answer so far. I'll optimize it.

Comment: @Gremo: I edited it and added one `all` function variant with `array_filter`, that was a good pointer by knittl as well.

Comment: +1 for the early-out-loop! I think this is the best code with regard to runtime and memory (even beats array_filter). I had something similar in mind too. Btw, you should be able to just do `$result=(bool)$a; foreach($a as $v) { if(!$f($v)) return false; } return $result;`, no need to AND all results

Comment: @knittl: Yeah right, good point, changed that. Sometimes when looking so closely to code, I miss some very valid points ;)

Comment: +1 also for me, despite many people that think that this is "misleading code". I find it very simple to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Better to pass in a function to map the values to booleans that you can then reduce to a final value.

```
function all($map, $data) {
  if (empty($data)) { return false; }
  $reduce = function($f, $n) {
    return $f && $n;
  };
  return array_reduce(array_map($map, $data), $reduce, true);
}

$gte0 = function($v) { return $v >= 0; };
$gte2 = function($v) { return $v >= 2; };

$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var_dump(all($gte0, $data));
var_dump(all($gte2, $data));
```

Then the result of the function remains expectant but the test can be slotted in as needed. You can go a step further and allow both the map and reduce function to be passed in.

```
function mr($map, $reduce, $data) {
  return array_reduce(array_map($map, $data), $reduce, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use PHP's [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) function, it will remove all 'falsy' values from an array if no callback is specified:

```
$a = array ( true, true, false );
var_dump($a == array_filter($a));
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any true() function in PHP, you should compare the value to true.

try

```
return ($f === $v1) && ($f === $v2);
```

instead of

```
return $f($v1) && $f($v2);
```

Comment: Confused by the first sentence -- should there be a period after PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
function all($f, array $arr)
{
    return empty($arr) ? false : array_reduce($arr, function($v1, $v2) use ($f) {
        return $f($v1) && $f($v2);
    }, true);
}

function isTrue($a)
{
    return true === $a;
}

all("isTrue", $test);
```

Comment: ...or `function isTrue($a) { return (bool) $a; }`, depending on requirements

Comment: @Gremo I think that the quoting of the parameter passed into `all()` is relevant. `"isTrue"` is a string in my example whereas `true` is a bool in yours.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Doesn't a logical operator like `&&` cast operands to bool in PHP?

Comment: @hakre Good point - but reaching a situation where you have a function that simply returns the only argument says to me there's probably a better way of doing it...